# How can I explain the intuition behind the First Isomorphism Theorem for modules or for rings to a lay person in mathematics

Tags: ring-theory, modules, module-isomorphism

How can I explain the intuition behind the First Isomorphism Theorem for modules or for rings to a lay person in mathematics, like to a non-scientist.  I want to use a very elementary example in life.

**Statement of the First Isomorphism Theorem:**  Let $R$ and $S$ be  rings and $f:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism.  Then $R/\ker(f)\cong f(R)$, where $\ker(f)$ is the kernnel of $f$.

Comment: Please give at least a reference.

Comment: Well when we say "It's 3 o'clock" we are working mod $12$ are we not? But this seems to me to be a Math Educators question.

Comment: Does a layperson even know what a ring is (much less a module)? That being said, what about "clock arithmetic" to illustrate the (natural projection) map from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$?

Comment: They layperson would first have to understand what a ring is, what a module is, what a module homomorphism is, what differentiates it from an isomorphism, what a kernel is, and what a quotient module is. All of this before you can even begin grasping the theorem. You'll lose any layperson before getting to that point of you try to explain this in one go.

Comment: Maybe take the example of the isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ with [$R[X]/(X^2+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/496781/305862) which can be turned into a way to **define** $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In the same spirit $R[\phi]/(\phi^2-\phi-1)$ as the natural framework for computation with polynomials expressions of $\phi$ (golden ratio).

Comment: Thank all for the ideas.  They have given me a clear picture on what to next.